# AS3 Memory Management reverse engineering

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, garbage-collection

Has anyone figured out how AS3 actually handles garbage collection? I'm having so many issues releasing memory in a game I'm developing.

Made a small demo:

```
public class MemoryTesting extends Sprite
{
    static protected var list:Array = null;

    public function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if( event.keyCode == 65 ){ //A key - adds memory
            if( list == null ){
                list = [];
                for( var index:int = 0; index < 10000000; ++index ){
                    list.push(new Matrix3D());
                }
            }
        }
        else{ //Any other key removes memory.
            if( list ){
                var size:int = list.length;
                for( var index:int = 0; index < size; ++index ){ 
                    list.pop();
                }
                list.length = 0;
                list = null;
            }
            System.gc();
        }
    }
}
```

Running Flash Player Debugger stand-alone 11.4r402 in Windows 7. Watching the Task Manager, with no keys pressed, the debugger sits idle at 11,000 K.

Pressing a (adding 10Mil Matrix3D classes) takes it up to 962,000 K.

Pressing another key (removing references to the Matrices and nulling the array) depends on how many times I press it.

- The first time we call GC  - drops to 255,000 K.
- The second GC call - 92,000 K.
- Third - 52,000 K.
- Forth - 42,000 K.
- Fifth - 39,000 K.
- Sixth & any consecutive times after sits at 38,000 K.

I hear people talking about the GC waiting for "opportune times" to collect. But this is an empty application, not even a enter_frame event and there is no amount of time you can leave it idle for it to remove the remaining 27,000 K (38,000 - 11,000).

Sitting at the new low, if we re-add the matrices we move back up to 975,000 K.

That is to say, 13,000 K more than the first time. If I repeat this add/remove, it stays the same, going back up to 975,000 K and down to 38,000 K.

Remember, there is nothing going on in this application. My actual application has 650mb of raw bitmap data, let alone 100mb of SWF to parse and 500mb of XML classes that I only use in initialisation code.

I've read multiple times that even calling GC manually is bad, let alone 6 times. But none of the Matrix3D's will be released if I don't.

How does anyone handle this? Shall I just call GC 6 times at the end of initialisation?

**Edit:**

I was testing in release mode for differences and whether, without the System.gc() call, that if it doesn't free the memory from flash, at the least re-uses it properly. It does eventually, but with a new, higher footprint. With a full list sits at 990,000 K, clearing it takes it to 1,050,000 K.

This is for data that initially cost us 962,000 K RAM. That's 90MB of weird internal flash GC memory. Let alone ignoring that it won't ever give the memory back to the OS (without the explicit GC calls).

Comment: For what it's worth, Adobe evangelists tend to recommend *not* using `System.gc()`. For one, it will only work in certain situations (see the live docs) and two, Flash releases memory when it needs more memory. The entire system is meant to be run automatically, not manually.

Comment: before you list.pop(); you should null out the object inside that index first list[i] = null; list.pop();, so this is probably your memory leak. The more objects you can null the better. Also System.gc() can only be called with the debug version of the player, the production version will ignore it.

Comment: @The_asMan, Nulling the index beforehand doesn't make a difference. I realize about the explicit call to System.gc(); but without it, flash stays at 1GB RAM forever, in an empty application.

Comment: @Jono Which means when you publish your SWF for regular users they will always see that 1 gig usage. Coming from a C++ you understand the importance of GC, but with AS3 you are trying to change something that is not meant to be changed by the programmer. This language was written originally with the designer in mind, and although in newer versions(as3) it is much more like a traditional language it still has its roots in AS1. Most say AS3 is a pig and that it takes up to much resources, but really does it matter.

Comment: Your example clamps down on 1 gig of ram and doesn't release it. At least that is what you are lead to believe. Just because the GC hasn't doesn't mean that 1 gig is not usable it just means flash is holding onto it. When the flash player feels it needs to release memory it will, that is if you marked everything properly for GCing.

Comment: When AS3 GCs it uses reference counting and mark and sweep. Mark and sweep is slow which is what you try to avoid by setting objects to null and removing event listeners and all references to that object. The player under normal situations will not free up memory since allocating memory is costly, only when there is a reason to free it up it will do so. With you calling System.gc() you are just forcing the cleaning which doesn't need to be done. My overall point is do your job and program your app properly and the player will do its job and clear memory when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Actionscript's GC is weird, nothing to say,

If you'll try to use something like this, it helps (I just tested and GC clears out the memory on the very first try (key click)), Just changed Array to Vector to test more quicker, just the same should happen with Array too. My enviroment is FlashCC in this case.

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.geom.Matrix3D;
import flash.net.LocalConnection;
import flash.system.System;
import flash.utils.setTimeout;

public class MemoryTesting extends Sprite
{
    var list:Vector.<Matrix3D> = null;

    function MemoryTesting()
    {
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
    }

    public function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {

        var matrx:Matrix3D;
        var index:int
        if (event.keyCode == 13)
        { 
            trace(System.totalMemory, "starting to fill...")

            if (list == null)
            {
                list = new Vector.<Matrix3D>
                for (index = 0; index < 1000000; ++index)
                {
                    matrx = new Matrix3D();
                    list.push(matrx);
                }
            }
            trace(System.totalMemory, " done...")
        }
        else
        { 
            if (list)
            {
                trace(System.totalMemory, " preparing to delete...")


                list.splice(0, list.length);
                list = null;

            }

            //force GC to work normally, it really helps (at least in my case)
            try
            {
                new LocalConnection().connect('foo');
                new LocalConnection().connect('foo');
            }
            catch (e:*)
            {
            }

            setTimeout(function()
                {
                    trace(System.totalMemory, " deleted")
                }, 50)

        }
    }
}
```

}

This strange snippet really helps on most cases

```
try {
new LocalConnection().connect('foo');
new LocalConnection().connect('foo');
} catch (e:*) {}
```

Here is the freat article:
http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/08/as3_resource_ma_2.html

Comment: Stuff like this makes me want to go back to C++. At least we have control there.

Comment: There should always be the option to switch off a language's GC and do things manually.